# Android record square video and concat

Tags: android, video, android-ndk, ffmpeg

Is there a way to record square (640x640) videos and concat them in Android? I looked up in the Internet and found some solutions. The solution seems to be "ffmpeg". However, to use ffmpeg I need to dive into NDK and build ffmpeg from its sources. Is there a solution by only using the Android SDK?

My basic needs are:

- Record multiple videos (square format)
- Resize captured videos (i.e. 480x480 to 640x640)
- Concat captured videos
- Rotate final video (clockwise 90)
- Final output will be in mp4 or mpg format

Comment: Look at [grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) and deep dive into Show + Capture Camera example. You will be able to record square video, resize, whatever by tweaking it. Full answer it too long to tell here. If you are lucky @fadden will pick up on your question, he is the author of grafika and may guide you better.

Comment: @KirillK grafika requires API 18. This is not a good choice for me. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Supporting API versions under 18 it still on my TODO list so I can not tell you ecactly. Look into jcodec library for example.  If you manage to implement this soon, let me know how you did it :) Here is good resource to start with: http://andrey.chernih.me/2014/06/28/video-recording-and-processing-in-android/

Comment: Did any of you get it (op and @KirillK)? I have been trying to do exactly the same approach you mention here. I cannot make it to work with grafika either. Let me know if you found something or try to guide me.

Comment: try this its best square camera for me github.com/CrazyOrr/FFmpegRecorder

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a solution by only using the Android SDK?

Not really.

Your primary video recording option is `MediaRecorder`, and it supports exactly nothing of what you list. For example, there is no requirement for any Android device to support taking square videos.

You are also welcome to use the camera preview stuff to assemble your own videos from individual frames. Vine does this, AFAIK. There, you could perhaps use existing `Bitmap` facilities to handle the cropping, resizing, and rotating. However, this will be slow, and doing this work in a way that can keep up with a reasonable frame rate will be difficult. Also, I do not know if there is a library that can stitch those frames together into a video, or blend in any sort of audio (camera previews are pure images).

Comment: Blows my mind how Vine/Instagram etc could have done it.